# UITableView disappears when I Add Missing Constraints to it

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, constraints

In my app, I have a navigation controller which is linked to a View Controller. This View Controller has a UITableView which fills it's entire size. When I run the app without adding constraints, this UITableView is slightly smaller in width and height than the simulator (iPhone 6). But when I add the missing constraints, the UITableView is no longer visible on the screen, with only the title bar at the top from the Navigation Controller still visible. I have tried pinning height and width, but to no avail.

All help appreciated.

EDIT 1: Here's a screenshot showing the list of constraints I use: https://i.stack.imgur.com/l34ZC.png

Comment: Can we have the constraints list? Or a pic of your storyboard?

Comment: I edited the original post :)

Answer (score 0):

I think your constraints are the problem here.

You align the tableView leading and trailing spaces to bottom layout, but i'm sure not sure if that is supposed to work.

Can you try to change both leading and trailing to a 0 space to superview?

Edit: A [good tuto](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithConstraints/WorkingwithConstraints.html) when you begin to work with constraints in interface builder.

Comment: I'll try this :) How do I change the leading and trailing to be superview? I double-click the constraints, and it gives me all the options apart from how to change the alignment from bottom layout to superview.

Comment: Delete your actual constraint and create a new one from the superview

Comment: Do I need to do this through code, or is it possible to do it through the interface builder? I can't find any tutorials for the latter :\